Combine two Draggable images together and change to another image for every iteration
I want to create this screen where when users drag one image (apparatus) onto another image.
If the combination is true (according to the procedure), it will change into another image.

Example: nailvarnish.png dragged onto hibiscus.png will turn into nailvarnishstroke.png

Else it will return an alert saying "Wrong steps. Try again."
As for the codes below, the dragging the images part is working. I figured maybe I have to use the combinedRules for every drag and drop combination, but since we are iterating through 7 procedures, I am stuck figuring out how to call it for every iteration.
It would be great if anyone could help me work on this feature! Long story short, this is a scientific version of the alchemy game :)
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Draggable from 'react-native-draggable';
import Header2 from '../Header2';
import ArrowButtonNext from '../components/ArrowButtonNext';
import ArrowButtonPrevious from '../components/ArrowButtonPrevious';

const ES_LandingPage = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [activeProcedure, setActiveProcedure] = useState(0);
  const [combined, setCombined] = useState({});

  const procedures = [
    {
      id: 1,
      text:
        '1. Apply a thin layer of transparent nail varnish on an area of 5mm x 5mm on the upper surface of the hibiscus leaf and water lily plant.',
      apparatus: ['hibiscus', 'waterlily', 'nail_varnish', 'nail_varnish'],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text:
        '2. Allow the varnished leaves to dry.',
      apparatus: ['hibiscus', 'waterlily', 'sun'],
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      text:
        '3. Carefully peel off the layer of nail varnish from the surface of the leaves using a pair of forceps.',
      apparatus: ['hibiscus', 'waterlily', 'forceps'],
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      text:
        '4. Place the peeled-off layer of nail varnish in a drop of water on a microscope slide.',
      apparatus: ['nailvarnishstroke', 'm_slip'],
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      text:
        '5. Cover the slide with a cover slip.',
      apparatus: ['m_slip', 'm_slip'],
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      text:
        '6. Observe the surface of the hibiscus leaf and water lily leaf using low power on a microscope.',
      apparatus: ['microscope', 'hibiscus', 'waterlily'],
    },
    {
      id: 7, 
      text:
        '7. Count and record the number of stomata present.',
      apparatus: ['microscope', 'hibiscus', 'waterlily'],
    },
    // Add more procedures as needed
  ];

  const images = {
    nail_varnish: require('./apparatus/nailvarnish.png'),
    hibiscus: require('./apparatus/hibiscus.png'),
    waterlily: require('./apparatus/waterlily.png'),
    m_slip: require('./apparatus/m_slip.png'),
    forceps: require('./apparatus/forceps.png'),
    nailvarnishstroke: require('./apparatus/nailvarnishstroke.png'),
    sun: require('./apparatus/sun.png'),
    microscope: require('./apparatus/microscope.png'),




    // Add more as needed
  };


  const combinationRules = {
    1: {
      'nailvarnish': {
        target: 'waterlily',
        combinedImage: 'nailvarnishstroke'
      },
      'nailvarnish': {
        target: 'hibiscus',
        combinedImage: 'nailvarnishstroke'
      }
    },
    2: {
      'nailvarnish': {
        target: 'hibiscus',
        combinedImage: 'nailvarnishstroke'
      }
    },
    // ...
  };

  const handleCombination = (apparatus, targetApparatus, procedureId, event) => {
    const rule = combinationRules[procedureId]?.[apparatus];

    if (rule && targetApparatus === rule.target) {
      // Adjust these coordinates to match your drop zone
      if (event.nativeEvent.pageX > 200 && event.nativeEvent.pageX < 900 && 
          event.nativeEvent.pageY > 500 && event.nativeEvent.pageY < 700) {
        setCombined((prev) => ({
          ...prev,
          [procedureId]: rule.combinedImage
        }));
      }
    }
  };

  const handleNextProcedure = () => {
    if (activeProcedure < procedures.length - 1) {
      setActiveProcedure(activeProcedure + 1);
      // setCombined(false); // Add this line
    }
  };
  
  const handlePrevProcedure = () => {
    if (activeProcedure > 0) {
      setActiveProcedure(activeProcedure - 1);
      // setCombined(false); // Add this line
    }
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollViewContent}>
      <>
        <Header2 navigation={navigation} />
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.dropZone} />

          <View style={styles.draggableContainer}>
            {procedures[activeProcedure]?.apparatus?.map((apparatus, index) => (
              <Draggable 
                key={index} 
                style={styles.draggableItem}
                onDragRelease={(event) => {
                  handleCombination(apparatus, 'nailvarnish', activeProcedure, event); // Adjust 'beaker' to your needs
                }}
              >
                <Image 
                  source={combined[activeProcedure] === apparatus ? images[combined[activeProcedure]] : images[apparatus]} 
                  style={styles.image} 
                />
              </Draggable>
            ))}
          </View>

          <Text style={styles.instructions}>{procedures[activeProcedure].text}</Text>

          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
  <ArrowButtonPrevious onPress={handlePrevProcedure} />
  <ArrowButtonNext onPress={handleNextProcedure} />
</View>
        </View>
      </>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  overlay: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 50, // Adjust the position as needed
    left: 100,
    opacity: 0.7, // Set the desired opacity
  },
  dropZone: {
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'black',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  draggableContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
  draggableItem: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  image: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    resizeMode: 'contain'
  },
  instructions: {
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: 'center',
    padding:30,
  },
  scrollViewContent: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default ES_LandingPage;

